# Test for absence of a pattern returns triples that match it

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

Why the first result of this query is matching both tests for absence while the values appear on the page?

```
#Leaders of Member states of the EU for which there is no value for gender or depiction in DBpedia

SELECT DISTINCT ?leader_No_gender ?leader_No_image

WHERE { 
?MS a dbo:Country; dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Member_states_of_the_European_Union>. 

{?MS dbo:leader ?leader_No_gender . 
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?leader_No_gender foaf:gender ?gender}
} 

UNION 

{?MS dbo:leader ?leader_No_image . 
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?leader_No_image foaf:depiction ?image}
} 
}
```

Comment: `dbr:Boyko_Borisov` redirects to `dbr:Boyko_Borissov`.

Comment: Right, a redirect, try `describe dbr:Boyko_Borisov`

Comment: you can use property paths like `dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/foaf:gender` (to cover transitive redirects you'd even need `dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/foaf:gender`) - note, Virtuoso still has some issue when using property paths in some places, I don't know why but if you use `dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/foaf:gender` **and** `dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/foaf:depiction` in your query, it'll fail with `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable '_::trans_subj_9_4' is used in subexpressions of the query but not assigned` - I remember some bug report w.r.t. property path, not sure of they are related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [property path-based queries](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dct%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%0D%0A++%3Fleader_No_gender+%0D%0A++%3Fleader_No_image%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A%3FMS+a+dbo%3ACountry%3B+dct%3Asubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3AMember_states_of_the_European_Union%3E.+%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B+%3FMS+dbo%3Aleader+%3Fleader_No_gender+.+%0D%0A++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B%3Fleader_No_gender+dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects%3F%2Ffoaf%3Agender+%3Fgender%7D%0D%0A%7D+%0D%0A%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B+%3FMS+dbo%3Aleader+%3Fleader_No_image+.+%0D%0A++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B%3Fleader_No_image+dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects%3F%2Ffoaf%3Adepiction+%3Fimage%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+) suggested by @AKSW [work on the latest Virtuoso Enterprise Edition (`08.03.3312`)](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dct%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%0D%0A++%3Fleader_No_gender+%0D%0A++%3Fleader_No_image%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A%3FMS+a+dbo%3ACountry%3B+dct%3Asubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3AMember_states_of_the_European_Union%3E.+%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B+%3FMS+dbo%3Aleader+%3Fleader_No_gender+.+%0D%0A++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B%3Fleader_No_gender+dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects%3F%2Ffoaf%3Agender+%3Fgender%7D%0D%0A%7D+%0D%0A%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B+%3FMS+dbo%3Aleader+%3Fleader_No_image+.+%0D%0A++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B%3Fleader_No_image+dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects%3F%2Ffoaf%3Adepiction+%3Fimage%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+) as hosts DBpedia-Live.  (Of course, these results are different than you'll find on the static DBpedia, still based on the 2016-10 dataset, and still running on Virtuoso `07.20.3230` which does still have the property path bug.)

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT 
  ?leader_No_gender 
  ?leader_No_image

WHERE 
  { 
    ?MS a           dbo:Country ; 
        dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Member_states_of_the_European_Union> . 

    { ?MS dbo:leader ?leader_No_gender . 
      FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?leader_No_gender dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/foaf:gender ?gender }
    } 

    UNION

    { ?MS dbo:leader ?leader_No_image . 
      FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?leader_No_image dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/foaf:depiction ?image }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? It's great that the result in dbpedia-live is consistent and that it can be checked because in that version of Virtuoso, property paths work. This still doesn't explain the discrepancy in the static DBpedia, especially considering that if there is one, the more actual should be the query result, not the page. Also, why dbr:Boyko_Borisov redirects to dbr:Boyko_Borissov? Shouldn't HTTP content negotiation work the same way for all URIs?

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov - Content negotiation does work for all URIs. However, Wikipedia edits happen, and it looks like the DBpedia extractors retain the original URI of an entity as the primary URI of that entity, when its Wikipedia page is renamed/moved, as happened with [Boyko_Borissov](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Boyko_Borissov&redirect=no) which was moved to [Boyko_Borisov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyko_Borisov). You'd have to discuss this choice of URI primacy with [the folks who produce the DBpedia datasets](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-discussion/).

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov - I don't understand the rest of your followup. Can you rephrase?